# A Question on forward-backward algorithm in CRF++

Tags: machine-learning, conditional-random-field

I’m a beginner of CRF++. A question have plagued me for many days. I’m exhausted~

Why the code in [`calcBeta()`](https://github.com/taku910/crfpp/blob/master/node.cpp#L25) is so like [`calcAlpha()`](https://github.com/taku910/crfpp/blob/master/node.cpp#L15)?

You know they two are very different in original forward-backward algorithm of HMM:

[image]
[image]

Ref: https://github.com/taku910/crfpp/issues/30#issuecomment-213297301

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's rewrite your formulas for short as
$$\alpha_j(t)=\log(\sum_k\exp(\alpha_k(t-1)+g(s_j,s_k)))+h(s_j,x_t)$$
$$\beta_j(t)=\log(\sum_k\exp(\beta_k(t+1)+g(s_k,s_j)+h(s_k,x_{t+1})))$$
In $\beta_j$, we can not take the $h(s_k,x_{t+1})$ out of the parenthesis as in $\alpha_j$ because it is dependent of $k$. Therefore you're suggesting that [`calcBeta`](https://github.com/taku910/crfpp/blob/master/node.cpp#L25) should be different from [`calcAlpha`](https://github.com/taku910/crfpp/blob/master/node.cpp#L15).

If we define $\beta'_j$ as
$$\beta'_j(t)=\beta_j(t)+h(s_j,x_{t})$$
we'll get
$$\beta'_j(t)=\log(\sum_k\exp(\beta_k(t+1)+g(s_k,s_j)+h(s_k,x_{t+1})))+h(s_j,x_{t})$$$$=\log(\sum_k\exp(\beta'_k(t+1)+g(s_k,s_j)))+h(s_j,x_{t})$$
which is in the same form as $\alpha_j$.

In fact the code is computing $\beta'_j(t_n)$, and that's why later in the [`calcExpectation`](https://github.com/taku910/crfpp/blob/master/node.cpp#L35) function when computing the marginals it needs to subtract the additional $h(s_j,x_{t})$ term (`cost`).

Comment: @QianHuang you're welcome.

Comment: @dontllo  Since the beta is actually beta', and it should subtract the cost in calcExpectation(https://github.com/taku910/crfpp/blob/master/node.cpp#L35). But one more question I have is why it does not subtract the cost in calcExpectation(https://github.com/taku910/crfpp/blob/master/path.cpp#L15) as the beta is also beta' in that place.

Comment: @QianHuang hi I'm not very familiar with the code, I suppose the other function is the marginal of a path, which is different of the marginal of a node. You can take a look at http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~mcollins/fb.pdf, the two marginals correspond to the $\mu(j,a)$ and $\mu(j,a,b)$ terms.